# How do I get the value of a property with reflection

Tags: reflection, kotlin

I want to use the values of all properties that have some annotation. For the most part my code works, I get all the properties and only take those that have that annotation.

```
private inline fun <reified A : Annotation> (target: Any) {
    target::class.memberProperties
                 .filter { it.annotations.any { annotation -> annotation is A } }
                 .forEach {
                     // How do I get the value here?
                 }
}
```

I wanted to use `it.get(...)` but `get` expects a `Nothing` as parameter. Same goes for `getter`. Calling `it.call(target)` does work but it looks wrong since there is an actuall `get` which I don't know how to invoke.

So what is the correct way of getting the properties value?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem boils down to the fact that `T::class` gives you a `KClass<T>`, whereas `t::class` gives you a `KClass<out T>`. Consider the following:

```
class Foo {
    val foo = 2
    val bar = 3
}

fun f() {
    val any: Any = Foo()
    any::class.memberProperties.forEach {
        println(it.get(2)) // Oops
    }
}
```

This would essentially attempt to access `2.foo` and `2.bar`, but it's not allowed because `get` errs on the side of caution instead of allowing a parameter of type `Any`. It appears doing `t.javaClass.kotlin` will produce a `KClass<T>`, however. Misusing it as above causes an `IllegalArgumentException`.

You can give the compiler some more help by providing a compile-time guarantee that the `KClass` will be for the type and nothing else:

```
private inline fun <reified A : Annotation, reified T : Any> foo(target: T) {
    T::class.memberProperties
            .filter { it.annotations.any { annotation -> annotation is A } }
            .forEach {
                println(it.get(target))
            }
}
```

Unfortunately, I don't know if it's possible to specify `A` while deducing `T` from `target`. I haven't found a way past calling it like `foo<Attr, Bar>(bar)`.

Alternatively, you can go through `javaClass`, though I'd wager it's less portable:

```
private inline fun <reified A : Annotation> foo(target: Any) {
    target.javaClass.kotlin.memberProperties
            .filter { it.annotations.any { annotation -> annotation is A } }
            .forEach {
                println(it.get(target))
            }
}
```

We know this won't run into the above problem because we pass the same object in both cases. This also looks nicer on the caller's side, which might be worth the portability hit, assuming there is one.

Comment: I think if you do `target.javaClass.kotlin.memberProperties` instead, you don't have to specify `T` at all.

Comment: How to do this in Kotlin/Native? The answer only explains it for JVM.

Comment: @xdevs23, I'm not too familiar, but I would guess that you're limited to the things that don't require adding in the runtime reflection library. The JVM is already set up to handle reflection whereas a native environment wouldn't be.